# AES: Why ShiftRows() before MixColumns()?

Tags: aes, permutation, diffusion

[image]
In above picture you can see a AES state array over 2 rounds through the S- and P-Boxes of AES. It's taken from [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/44532/how-2-rounds-in-aes-achieve-full-diffusion/44585) and intends to show how 2 rounds of transformation are necessary to achieve full diffusion after only the first byte has changed.

If one would MixColumns() before MixRows() diffusion, one would reach diffusion one step earlier. So I wonder what is the reason to ShiftRows() before MixColumns()?

Comment: If one would MixColumns() before MixRows() diffusion, one would reach diffusion one step earlier, could you please explain it more?

Comment: @hardyrama Let's ignore the `SubBytes()` Operation since it doesn't affect Diffusion. If we `MixColumns()` in the fist step, the changed byte diffuses into the whole first column. After `ShiftRows()` is applied, theres one changed byte in every column. After another `MixColumn()` operation every byte in the state array has changed, requiring only 3 steps until diffusion was reached.

Comment: Take a look at the comments of [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/does-changing-the-order-of-the-steps-within-a-round-affect-the-security-of-aes/41037#41037)