# Is the order of the steps in AES commutative?

Tags: aes

Say I wanted to change the order of the 4 steps within a round in AES, would it change the final result?

Comment: What did you research? There are 4! possible positions and actually it depends on the order. This answer contains the possible case [Does changing the order of the steps within a round affect the security of AES?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/does-changing-the-order-of-the-steps-within-a-round-affect-the-security-of-aes) `ShiftRows and SubBytes are commutative, They are not commutative MixColumns`

Answer (score 4):

We have four components of [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) round function:

- `SubBytes` performs per-byte substitution operation.
- `ShiftRows` is a permutation of bytes of the state.
- `MixColumns` is a function that works on each column of the state.
- `AddRoundKey` adds 128 bits of the round key to the corresponding bytes of the state.

The only two operations (that follow each other in the original order) that commute are `SubBytes` and `ShiftRows` since the first works independently on each byte (and the operation for each byte is the same) and the second one just reshuffles the bytes.

If you swap e.g. `MixColumns` and `AddRoundKey` you will get a different result, because instead of adding the round key $rk$ you will effectively add `MixColumns`($rk$) which is a different value for non-zero round key.

Comment: Yet the swap of `MixColumns` and `AddRoundKey` is possible, if one adjust the key injected by `AddRoundKey` by first applying `InvMixColumns` to the key (that's necessary to obtain the same result as the original AES). That's part of why there is no `MixColumns`in the last round: `AddRoundKey` and `MixColumns` are close enough to commutative that `MixColumns` in the last round would have little cryptographic value.

Comment: @fgrieu: Correct, it's possible but as you pointed out it needs a modification of the key schedule, so it may not count as the original AES.